# Angularjs division by scope variable fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use [angular-timer](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer).

This works:

```
{{ (seconds / 10) * 100 }}
```

But this one does not:

```
{{ (seconds / secondsToAnswer ) * 100 }
```

(it evaluates to NaN)

However, I set the `secondsToAnswer` to 10 in the controller: `$scope.secondsToAnswer = 10;`
It happens outside the directive as well.

Full code:

*HTML*

```
<timer interval="1000">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped"
         role="progressbar"
         aria-valuenow="20"
         aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="100"
         style="width: {{ (seconds / secondsToAnswer) * 100 }}%">
    </div>
  </div>
</timer>
```

*JS*

```
'use strict';

vocabApp.controller('PracticeController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.expressions = [
    { expression:'cat', meaning:'macska' },
    { expression:'dog', meaning:'kutya' },
    { expression:'whale', meaning:'bálna' }
  ];

  //$scope.timerRunning = true;

  $scope.startTimer = function () {
    $scope.secondsToAnswer = 10;
    $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
    $scope.timerRunning = true;
  };

  $scope.stopTimer = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
    $scope.timerRunning = false;
  };

  $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, args) {
    console.log('timer-stopped args = ', args);
  });

})
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a timing issue. The page expression {{...}} is getting evaluated prior to secondsToAnswer getting set. Try making secondsToAnswer a function that returns the value you are interested in.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, I've tried it, but it's something else.

Comment: It's hard to read their example code due to the fact that all the open angle brackets are changed to &lt; on git. But I wonder if the issue isn't that your controller scope that sets the secondsToAnswer variable and the directive scope that sets the seconds aren't connected.

Comment: can you wrap you timer directive with `ng-if='secondsToAnswer'`, also initialize the `secondsToAnswer` as the first line of the controller, and let me know the result...

Comment: I guess the missing `}` from your second example is an oversight?

Comment: how are you using PracticeController

Answer (score 5):

It is because `$scope.secondsToAnswer = 10;` will only be executed when startTimer runs, untill that time `$scope.secondsToAnswer` will be undefined.

If you make `$scope.secondsToAnswer = 10;` the first line in your controller, then it should work.

Comment: I think it WAS the first line when them problem first occured, but I'll check it when I get back home.

Comment: It is that, plus something else :) I don't know if your source code is complete, but there is no declaration for `seconds`. You could do a `console.log($scope.seconds);` at the beginning of your controller to see if it has some value.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem comes from two places.
First as [Sander_P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864395/sander-p) pointed out, `$scope.secondsToAnswer` should be defined at the top of your controller and not in within the `startTimer` function. 
Now the other thing is that your controller wraps the `timer` directive but should actually be inside it.

For example:

```
 <timer interval="1000">
        <div ng-controller="PracticeController" class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" 
                 role="progressbar"
                 aria-valuenow="20"
                 aria-valuemin="0"
                 aria-valuemax="100"
                 style="width: {{ (seconds / secondsToAnswer) * 100 }}%">
            </div>
        </div>
  </timer>
```

---

**[I made a working jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/egfb8wz0/4/):**

```
var vocabApp = angular.module("APP", ['timer']);
vocabApp.controller('PracticeController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.secondsToAnswer = 100;

    $scope.expressions = [{
        expression: 'cat',
        meaning: 'macska'
    }, {
        expression: 'dog',
        meaning: 'kutya'
    }, {
        expression: 'whale',
        meaning: 'bálna'
    }];

    //$scope.timerRunning = true;

    $scope.startTimer = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
        $scope.timerRunning = true;
    };

    $scope.stopTimer = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
        $scope.timerRunning = false;
    };

    $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, args) {
        console.log('timer-stopped args = ', args);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things

1. The $scope.secondsToAnswer should be declared outside the function globally not when startTimer is called.
2. In HTML code, you should wrap the area where you need to use the scope. In this case, inside the timer directive